# How can i fix error during sls deployment?

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, serverless

Hello I get this error while trying to deploy serverless to AWS:

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: "service" property is not accessible (configured behind variables which cannot be resolved at this stage)
```

Environment:

```
linux, 
node 14.20.1
framework 3.33.0 (local) 
plugin 6.2.3 
SDK 4.3.2
```

Comment: Hi, can you share that command you were running and the directory structure of your code-base?